# is there a way to make an object follow another object plus always points/looks towards the camera

Tags: c#, object, unity-game-engine

i am working on a project and need help making an object follow another object but at the same time one end should point towards the camera.I have tried the lookAT method but it is not working properly.

Comment: Please share that `LookAt` you have tried and also it would help if you can clarify how should the object follow the other object.

Comment: gun.transform.LookAt(Camera.main.transform.position);
gun.transform.position=enemy.position;

Comment: Well, first of all you do not need to worry about the backend of the gun. You can just place it in front of the camera initially and the just use `LookAt`

Comment: its an AR game so placing the object in front of the camera is not working.

Comment: It would work if you anchor it

Answer (score 1):

`LookAt` works perfectly for 3D objects.

These are the possibilities that `LookAt` may fail to work as you expect:

1. You want a **2D** object to look at a point.
2. The visually-considered **front-side** of the object is **not** its x+ side. mainly because:

   - The 3D model is carelessly fabricated using a third party software.
   - The object is inside another object and is rotated in its place.
3. You are **manipulating** the rotation of the object elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Pointing the other object is really simple. You only need to use the [LookAt](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.LookAt.html), like this:

```
GameObject target;

transform.LookAt(target.transform);
```

For following the target, I see multiple apporaches. You can for example make the object also use the script with LookAt and when you move the main oject, move also the follower.
Another more complex way would be set a maximum separation distance where the object will move towards its target. This one would also use LookAt.
If you chose the last one, you can do something like this:

```
const float MaxDistance = 5.0f // The maximum distance the target can go away before following it.
float speed = 2.0f;

if(Vector3.Distance(transform.position, target.transform.position) > MaxDistance)
{
    transform.LookAt(target.transform);

    transform.position += Vector3.forward * speed * Time.deltaTime;
}
```

You should attach this to the Update or a Couroutine.

Answer (score 0):

A specific object goes straight to the target object as follows:

```
//Declare a variable that points to a specific object and a target obj variable
public GameObject obj1;
public GameObject obj2;

GameObject targetObj;

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Alpha1))
        OnChangedTarget(obj1);

    if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Alpha2))
        OnChangedTarget(obj2);

    UpdateObjPos(Camera.main.gameObject);
}

//Keep distance from target obj
void UpdateObjPos(GameObject followObj, float width = 10f, float height = 10f)
{
    if (targetObj == null)
        return;

    followObj.transform.LookAt(targetObj.transform);

    float posX = targetObj.transform.position.x + width;
    float posY = targetObj.transform.position.y + width;
    float posZ = targetObj.transform.position.z + height;

    followObj.transform.position = new Vector3(posX, posY, posZ);
}

//Declare function to select target obj
void OnChangedTarget(GameObject obj)
{
    Debug.Log("Target Changed : " + obj.name);
    targetObj = obj;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

### Solution

Just inherit your desired object to the main game object withe the main game object which is your player.I never used any c# code script for this purpose. if you want to follow two objects to follow each other just inherit main game object . In that way the second game object will follow the required main player . The camera will be inherit as well if you want camera to follow both of them . As far as the points the camera is concerned you need to play with unity tool and adjust the x,y and z axis according to the position of camera . I would suggest to put camera in front of both game objects and just turn the face of  camera toward the game objects .

### picture

[image: The example of inherited game object with camera]